# Adjust Image View to Image (Android Studio)

Tags: android, imageview, png

I would like to know how you adjust the "hitbox" of an ImageView to the Image inside, so that there are no empty spaces around the image. I want to make a game and so it feels odd when you click on an empty space next to the Image but it still counts as "a click on the image". I would really appreciate help.
Thank you in advance.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/soraka"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="300dp"
    android:maxHeight="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all open your image in some image editor and check if it fills entire canvas. Second - use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. But be carefull with aspect ratio:

> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This
>   may change the aspect ratio of the src.

Also remove all paddings, margins from `ImageView`.

Comment: I added this but it didnt work for me, i will add the code i have to my question

Comment: could you also add a screenshot and maybe attach that image?

Comment: Nevermind it is working now, Thank you for your answer

Comment: this and adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` worked for me. why is this not the default, anyway?